# Swift Alamofire migration parsing JSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

On migrating to recent versions am finding it hard to get and print the fields of name, age, and dob from JSON using Alamofire 4 parsing in Swift 3.

JSON FORMAT

```
"SetValues": {   
"data":
[
  {
    "Name": yyyyy ,
    "Age": 13,
    "DOB": "2017-06-08",
  }

  {
    "Name": xxxx ,
    "Age": 33,
    "DOB": "2015-06-08",
  }
]
}
```

I tried

```
Alamofire.request(url!,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: nil,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: headers)

        .responseJSON{ response in

                  let datamsg = jsonmsg?["SetValues"] as? [String : Any]

                  let dataset = datamsg?["data"] as? [String : Any]
                  let setValues = datamsg?["data"]
                  print (setValues[0]["Name"] as Any)
              }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: I tried 

Alamofire.request(url!,
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: nil,
                          encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                          headers: headers)

            .responseJSON{ response in
 
                      let datamsg = jsonmsg?["SetValues"] as? [String : Any]
                        
                        let dataset = datamsg?["data"] as? [String : Any]
                        let setValues = datamsg?["data"]
                          print (setValues[0]["assetDateId"] as Any);

Comment: Put it in the question.

Comment: So what happens when you run your code? What is `jsonmsg`? It isn't defined in your code.

Comment: let jsonmsg = response.result.value as? [String : Any] 
thats where my entire json response goes in but when tried taking one element from setValues , it says type of any has no subscript members

Comment: (Make sure to update your post with that missing information.) Have you checked to make sure that `jsonmsg` is what you expect it to be by printing it out? You can also try changing `Any` to `AnyObject`.

Comment: I tried them but in vain! I also tried casting it to dictionary , array but with the index being used , I get the error type of any has no subscript members

Comment: `dataset` is an Array (of dictionaries), not a dictionary, so you can't do `as? [String : Any]`, it should be at least `as? [Any]`, and in your case `as? [[String: Any]]`.

Comment: i am able to get values in the dataset but when i try to pick one value like name from that , am shown the error !

Comment: `type of any has no subscript members` And you look for it? It has plenty of question on SO about it. And `as? [[String: Any]]` (`let dataset = datamsg?["data"] as? [[String: Any]], print(dataSet[0]["Name"])`  may have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
let dataset = datamsg?["data"] as? [String : Any]
```

as seen from the JSON response string it should be like below

```
let dataset = datamsg?["data"] as? [[String : Any]]

let name = dataset?[0]["Name"] as? String
```

Comment: Thank you all for your time and efforts. The work around solution I got finally was : The type of Any member cannot take subscripts , so if I need  index value to traverse through the parsed json, i must cast the initial Json response to dictionary Then find the data part and use as? [String : Any].